# Loop through MySQL results PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'd like to make a loop that loops through the results from the following code:

```
$check_events = "SELECT * FROM events_meedoen WHERE username=:username";
    $stmt_check = $db->prepare($check_events);
    $stmt_check->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt_check->execute();

    $events_row = $stmt_check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
    $event_id = $events_row['event_id'];

    $get_event = "SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE event_id=:event_id";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($get_event);
    $stmt->bindParam(':event_id', $event_id);
    $stmt->execute();
```

So, for example, I'd like to get all results with the `$event_id` gotten by checking the agenda for all events that the user is signed up for.

This should result in 2 for my account, which it does not because it only checks once. Any help? :)

Comment: What query should return 2? Where's your loop? Waht is your question exactly?

Comment: You might be interested in sql JOINs. You can query the data you want with one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put your call to `fetch` in a while loop.  As you can see from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php), `PDO::fetch` calls the *next* record from the result set.

so, something like this will loop through all of the results:

```
while($events_row = $stmt_check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
    $event_id = $events_row['event_id'];
    // do something with the $events_row array here
}
```

because `PDO::fetch` returns `false` when it hits the end of the result set, the while loop knows when to stop.

Comment: And if there's only exactly one record per query expected?

Comment: then itll only do it once

Comment: ...and the loop is not necessary, is it? I'd rather wait for the explanation what  "should result in 2 for my account" means ;-)

Comment: he asked for a loop. 'So, I'd like to make a loop that loops through the results from the following code:'